# "A Hen in the Wind"?

Tags: meaning, nuances, expressions

I just watched the 1948 film "A Hen in the Wind," directed and co-written by Yasujiro Ozu. I'm guessing the title is a reference to a Japanese proverb or traditional metaphor. Does anyone recognize it? Does anyone know what it means? (I don't speak or read Japanese, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Hen_in_the_Wind) has the following translation in Japanese characters: **風の中の牝鶏【めんどり】**.)

Comment: The English title is a direct translation of the Japanese title, fwiw.

Comment: The only proverb I could think of that contains "hen" in it is 「雌鶏歌えば家滅ぶ。」 but I have no idea if it has anything to do with the film title as I have never seen the film myself.

Comment: I don't think there's another obvious proverb on which this film was based, either.

Comment: L'electeur: Thank you for responding. Unfortunately, I don't read or speak Japanese, so could you – or whoever happens to be reading this at the moment – respond with an English  translation of 「雌鶏歌えば家滅ぶ。」? Thanks, Ron Stringer

Comment: P.S. Thank you to senshin and naruto as well.

Comment: Literally, it means "If the hen sings, the home will perish."  Figuratively, it means that if the wife gains more power than the husband, their home will be ruined.

Comment: Note: by *"sings"*, the proverb refers to the hen being the one that crows in the morning, instead of the rooster.  Compare the dated English expression about *"who wears the pants in the family"*.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be based on a proverb or expression.  (Maybe there's a hint that the husband is a "weathercock" (cock in the wind) -- opportunistic, unprincipled ... .)

The first thing the heroin Tokiko did was to sell her wardrobe one by one  -- she had to pluck her feathers like a hen.  Then she had to be plucky and strong in the cold wind.

As the following comment says, the title may refer to the women in general at the time. I suppose that when the movie came out, the meaning of the title was obvious to the general public.

http://ameblo.jp/jahyon2002/entry-10937011475.html

> 11. タイトルの意味  --　おっしゃる通り、風の中の牝鶏はヒロインの事であり、
>                不本意な形で自立を余儀無くされた女性全般なのでしょうね。